# Firebase user login state beetween Activities

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working in Android Studio on an app that uses Google Maps API and Firebase for signing in.

I've the map activity with a button that opens a new activity, the sign in one (I currently used only the Google sign in).

In the map Activity I have also a longClickListener which on a the long click on the map adds a marker to it.

What I would like to do is to add the marker only if the user is logged, therefore I need to check the user state (logged or not).

Now, I've read that with Firebase the user state is always "saved" and I can check it by using the code

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in

                } else {
                    // User is signed out

                }
                // ...
            }
        };
```

But I don't know where to put this code.
In the "map" Activity? In which function?

This is my MapsActivity code

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private static final String TAG = "Maps_Activity";
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }


    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_name) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(final LatLng latLng) {

                    //Function that adds marker
                    popUpMarker(latLng);

            }
        });

    }

    public void popUpMarker(final LatLng ll)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("Confrm");
        builder.setMessage("Add marker here?");

        //IF YES
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Add marker to map
                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(ll)
                        .anchor(0.0f, 1.0f)
                        .title("My marker");

                mMap.addMarker(marker);

                Intent add = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, AddMarker.class);
                startActivity(add);

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        //IF NO
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                // Do nothing
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }



    public void  do_login(MenuItem mi) {
        Intent add = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Login.class);
        startActivity(add);
```

This is my Login code

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
    private static final String TAG = "Login_Activity";

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    private SignInButton SignIn;
    private Button Logout;
    private TextView p;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        SignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.google_btn);
        Logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_logout);
        p=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.prova);

        Logout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        Logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mAuth.signOut();
            }
        });


        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in

                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                    p.setText(user.getEmail().toString());
                    SignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Logout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                    p.setText("Not signed in");
                    SignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Logout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                // ...
            }
        };


        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
        // options specified by gso.
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Error API Client", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        SignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signIn();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            }
            else {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                // ...
            }

        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the "map" activity?

Should you be checking if the user is logged in within the map activity? How did they get to the Map Activity without being logged in?

`onAuthStateChanged` is to check if the user has switched from logged in or not, not to simply say "user is currently available". For that, you may use

```
boolean loggedIn = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null;
```

> In which function?

How about in the click listener, like you said you wanted?

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(final LatLng latLng) {
        //Function that adds marker
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            popUpMarker(latLng);
        } else {
            // Redirect to login page?
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I managed to do it by adding the boolean variable that you suggested! By the way the application  starts with the MapsActivity, users don't need to be logged to see it. Currently they need to be logged only if they want to add marker .

Comment: Update: if i put "FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();", i got an error sayng "cannot resolve symbol firebaseAuth"

Comment: Well, yeah. That variable isn't defined, so define it

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it:

Put the `AuthStateListener` in `LoginActivity` and if `user` is `null` (i.e. the user has signed out), then start the `LoginActivity` itself so that user can log in or quit the app.